# When I create the dependency property, the GetValue and SetValue methods are mandatory?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

When I create a dependency property, the property in c #, I enter with the GetValue and SetValue methods? I must always do it this way??

```
public double Minimum
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); } 
}
```

Comment: Yes. Is that bothering you? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to do it that way.

Dependency properties work a bit differently than normal properties, you can't just get/set them like a variable, you need to use the `Get/SetValue` functions.

You can *remove* the property accessor for the DP if you wish, but its very convenient.

Note that creating it is very fast with the `propdp` snippet.

For example, if you didn't have the property you could retrieve the DP value with:

```
(double)GetValue(MinimumProperty);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "can remove the backing property"??

Comment: @missenna I mean that having the property at all is not mandatory. You can access the DP value through `Get/SetValue`. However, repeating that call everywhere is annoying, so we use a standard C# property to hide it.

Comment: Sorry, but to better understand, could you give me an example of code?

Comment: @missenna Sure, can you be more specific? If you didn't have the property, you would use the method currently in `get/set` to access the DP.

Comment: I saw you edited the answer with an example. So I could eliminate "return"?

Comment: @missenna Only if you aren't inside the property `get` function. Do you understand how properties work?

Comment: `public double Minimum
{
    (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); 
   //I did well?
}`

Comment: @missenna That code doesn't make any sense. Properties must be done with get/set functions. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?